# My flutter project gets stuck when I run Flutter Pub Upgrade or even Flutter Pub Cache Repair

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-pub

I have been working on a flutter project for a while now but I keep getting these problems. When I clone my project from git, I can't resolve my dependencies as Flutter Pub Upgrade gets stuck. The first time I encountered this problem, I checked my firewall and enabled my VSCode (which I use for the development) and it worked fine. I got to get and upgrade the packages in my yaml file. Now I am getting the same problem but I already checked my firewall and nothing is disabled or blocked. Even Flutter Pub Cache Repair is stucked too. But Flutter Pub Get works on my CMD. The others get stuck.

I have tried reinstalling my flutter and it doesn't work. Anyone else experienced this issue?